# Add joins by default to Laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have created a method in my Laravel model which added a few `leftJoins` to the query builder, but I'm wondering if there is a nicer way to call it.

My model:

```php
class Stock extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'stock_id';

    static public function scopeJoinStocksQuery($query){
        return $query->leftJoin('parts','parts.part_id','=','stocks.part_id')->leftJoin('colors','colors.color_id','=','stocks.color_id');
    }
}
```

The way I'm calling the model now:

```php
$stock = new Stock;
$stock = Stock::scopeJoinStocksQuery($stock);

if($input){
    $stock->where('model','LIKE','%'.$input.'%');
}

$stocks = $stock->offset(10)
            ->limit(50)
            ->orderBy('model', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

The way I'd like to be able to write it:

```php
$stock = Stock::scopeJoinStocksQuery();

if($input){
    $stock->where('model','LIKE','%'.$input.'%');
}

$stocks = $stock->offset(10)
            ->limit(50)
            ->orderBy('model', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

Is it possible to tidy up the code and write it in the last way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
$stock = Stock::scopeJoinStocksQuery();
```

to

```
$stock = Stock::joinStocksQuery();
```

When working with scopes you omit the `scope` prefix from the method name, see more about [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes).

Comment: Should be `Stock::joinStocksQuery()`